# matplotlib CGI doesn't work

Tags: apache, web, matplotlib, cgi

I'd like to publish a figure generated by matplotlib on web site based on Windows Apache Server.

A [Scipy example code](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Using_MatPlotLib_in_a_CGI_script) (below) shows just tiny icon which link is broken.

The code of related question on this BBS also just shows icon.

My code is below. I guess the code is correct, but I probably mess up some setting of Apache Server or matplotlib. Any comments is welcome.

```
#!c:/python27/python

import os, sys
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

os.environ['HOME'] = r'C:\temp'

import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('Agg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,1,4,2,6,4,8])

print "Content-Type: image/png\n"

plt.savefig( sys.stdout, format='png' )
```

Comment: Can you add any details about your apache set up?  I am not sure there is enough detail here to answer the question.

Comment: What happens when you visit this CGI resource via a web browser?